# ¿Cómo puedo agregarle una interfaz a la estructura de un proyecto que estoy creando en C?

Tags: c

Estoy creando un menú de inventario de objetos básico, pero no logro resolver como hacerlo un menú, o sea que al al elegir cierta opción me lleve a tal acción.
Intento realizar un menú pequeño de inventario de 10 productos máximo donde pueda darle una interfaz buena y sencilla pero no sé con claridad como hacerlo.

**Código del menú de mi inventario**

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct producto{

    char nombre[30];

    char descripcion[60];

    float precio;

}items[10];



int main(){




    while(opcion!=5){

    system("cls");

    printf("*****************\n");

    printf("*Menu de inventario  *\n");

    printf("*****************\n");

    printf("\nSeleccione una opcion:\n\n1. Agregrar producto\n2. Eliminar producto \n3. Modificar precio \n4. Mofificar cantidad de stock  \n5. Salir\n\n");

    scanf("%d",&opcion);

    switch (opcion){        

        case 1:

            AgregarProducto(nombre);

            break;

        case 2:

            EliminarProducto(Nombre);

            printf("* El producto fue eliminado *\nPresione una tecla para continuar...");

            getch();

            break;

        case 3:

            ();

            break;

        case 4:

            printf();

            break;
        case 5:

            printf("**** CERRANDO *****\nPresione una tecla para continuar...");

            break;

        default:

            printf("Seleccione una opcion valida.\nPresione una tecla para continuar...");

            getch();//permite pausar hasta ingresar una tecla

        }

    }
    int i=0;

    for (i=0;i<10;i++){

        printf("Ingrese el nombre del producto: \n");

        scanf("%s",&items[i].nombre);

        printf("Ingrese la descripcion del producto: \n");

        scanf("%s",&items[i].descripcion);

        printf("Ingrese el precio del producto: \n");

        scanf("%f",&items[i].precio);

        system("cls");

    }

    for(i=0;i<10;++i){

        printf("%d Nombre del producto: %s\n Descripcion: %s\n Precio: %.2f\n",i+1,items[i].nombre,items[i].descripcion, items[i].precio);

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Estoy aprendiendo y no comprendo muy bien, pero intento que al elegir tal opción ésta me lleve o ejecute lo que le pido, Por ejemplo si elijo 1 me salga la opción 1 `agregar objeto` para que no se vea asó como la siguiente imagen.

[image: Imagen referencia de la cual no quiero que se vea mi interfaz]

a que se vea algo asi

[image: ejemplo de menú de la cual si deseo que se vea mi interfaz]

Comment: Y donde esta definida la variable opcion?

Answer (score 0):

Como dice @gbianchi en el comentario, primero debes declarar la variable `opcion` (y te recomiendo inicializarla).
El empleo del `swithc-case` te permite ejecutar ciertas partes de código en función del valor que tome `opción`. Como sólo estás intentando mostrar el menú como en la segunda imagen, deberías tener un código así:

```
int main(){


    uint9_t opcion=0;


    system("cls");

    printf("**************************\n");

    printf("*   Menu de inventario   *\n");

    printf("**************************\n");

    printf("\nSeleccione una opcion:\n\n1. Agregrar producto\n2. Eliminar producto \n3. Modificar precio \n4. Mofificar cantidad de stock  \n5. Salir\n\n");

    scanf("%d",&opcion);

    while (opcion != 5) {

        switch (opcion){        

            case 1:

                AgregarProducto(nombre);

                break;

            case 2:
                // AGREGAR RESTO DEL CÖDIGO .....
```

Date cuenta que para actuar sobre el bucle `while` debes **conocer y manejar** el valor de la variable `opcion`.
Incluso, te recomiendo además (para dejarlo bonito como quieres), que te crees una función que borre la consola, pinte el menú y te solicite el valor de `opcion`. De este modo, cuando se ejecute cualquiera de las opciones se vuelva a pinta el menú siempre y cuando no se introduzca el valor `5` (opción de salir).